# Solving $\int_{\partial \mathcal{D}(0,\frac{1}{2})} \dfrac{\log(1+z)}{(4z-1)^2}dz$ in the context of complex analysis

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

We are given the integral
\begin{align}
\int_{\partial \mathcal{D}(0,\frac{1}{2})} \dfrac{\log(1+z)}{(4z-1)^2}dz
\end{align}
where $\partial D(0,1/2)$ is the normal counterclockwise circle center $0$ and radius $1/2$.

How can we compute it using Complex Analysis techniques?

Using the obvious parameterization of a circle in complex analysis, where we set
\begin{align}
\gamma(t) = a + re^{i \phi} \overbrace{\mapsto}^{a=0, \ r=1/2} \dfrac{e^{i \phi}}{2}, \ \phi \in \left[ 0,2\pi \right].
\end{align}

Putting it though on the original and after some computations yield
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \dfrac{\log \left( \dfrac{2+e^{i\phi}}{2} \right)}{(2e^{i\phi}-1)^2}d\phi
\end{align}
which obviously does not solve in closed form.

Any ideas?

**Final answer:** I took the inspiration from @Bongo's post and also [this post](https://www.math.usm.edu/schroeder/slides/comp_var/18_residue_theorem.pdf).

I am trying to bring the original integral to the form
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\Phi(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}
\end{align}
where $\Phi(z) = \dfrac{\log (1+z)}{16}$ and the only pole at $z_0 = 1/4$ order $m=2$.

We already know that the residue at given point is
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Res}_{z=z_0}(f) = \dfrac{\Phi^{(m-1)}(z_0)}{(m-1)!}.
\end{align}

For $m=2$ and $z_0 = 1/4$ we can have
\begin{align}
\Phi'(z) = \dfrac{1}{16} \left( \dfrac{1}{1+z} \right) \overbrace{\mapsto}^{z_0=1/4} \dfrac{1}{20}.
\end{align}

So by the residue theorem
\begin{align}
\int_{\partial \mathcal{D}(0,\frac{1}{2})} \dfrac{\log(1+z)}{(4z-1)^2}dz &= 2\pi i \sum \left( \text{residues} \right)\\
&= 2\pi i \dfrac{1}{20}\\
&= \dfrac{\pi i}{10}.
\end{align}

Comment: Look up [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem).

Comment: So it's zero? Talking about the final answer

Comment: Whoops. I should quote residue theorem instead.

Comment: Haha yes I am pretty sure it's non zero.

Comment: It is nonzero. It is $\pi i/10$!

Comment: Ah you seem so certain about it while I see this for the first time sadly. Will have to work my way through this

Comment: “the normal clockwise circle”- Do you mean counterclockwise? If you do indeed mean clockwise, then I think the answer should be $-\frac{\pi i}{10}$.

Comment: @KStarGamer very good. I was referring to the "normal" mathematical direction, that is counterclockwise. Will fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the  Cauchy's differentiation formula the integral it's solved immediately: $$f'(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2}\text dz.$$
log($1+z$) is holomorphic in $\mathcal D(0,\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon)$. $$\oint _{\partial \mathcal D(0,\frac{1}{2})}\frac{\log(1+z)}{(4z-1)^2}=\frac{2\pi i}{2\pi i}\oint _{\partial \mathcal D(0,\frac{1}{2})}\frac{\log(1+z)}{16(z-\frac{1}{4})^2}=$$ $$=\frac{2\pi i}{16}\cdot \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint _{\partial \mathcal D(0,\frac{1}{2})}\frac{\log(1+z)}{(z-\frac{1}{4})^2}=\frac{2\pi i}{16}\cdot \left( log(1+a)  \right)_{a=1/4}'=$$  $$=\frac{2\pi i}{16}\cdot\left( \frac{1}{1+a}  \right)_{a=1/4}= \frac{2\pi i}{16}\cdot\frac{4}{5}=\frac{\pi i}{10}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You just write the function as $\dfrac{log(1+z)}{16(z-\dfrac{1}{4})^{2}}$.

We set $z-\dfrac{1}{4}=w$ and we expand the

$log(1+z)=z-\dfrac{z^{2}}{2}+\dfrac{z^{3}}{3}-..... $and setting

$z=w+\dfrac{1}{4}$ we get the coefficient of $\dfrac{1}{w}$ (the Residue) as

$\dfrac{1}{16}(1-\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{4^{2}}-...)=\dfrac{1}{16}.\dfrac{4}{5}=\dfrac{1}{20}.$

By the residue theorem, since the pole is in $(0,1/2)$ we get

$I=2\pi\,i\,\dfrac{1}{20}=\dfrac{\pi\,i}{10}$